# Terraform resource has changed, but all its attributes are unchanged

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm seeing this after I run `terraform plan -refresh-only`:

```
# aws_route53_record.my_record has changed
~ resource "aws_route53_record" "my_record" {
     id      = "MYZONEID_some.url.com_CNAME"
     name    = "some.url.com"
     # (5 unchanged attributes hidden)
  }
```

The resource is marked as having changed, but all attributes are unchanged. Why is terraform saying there's a change when it would seem like there isn't?

Comment: You may want to report this to the AWS provider, but it will probably be triaged due to being a non-functional issue, or possibly redirected to a Terraform plugin (if the underlying module is causing the false diff).

Comment: Can you show the relevant terraform?

Comment: do you have a `depends_on`  meta attribute in the resource? and if so is that item being updated/replaced?

Comment: It could be due to `lifecycle` meta-argument with `ignore_changes` attribute. Does this resource got any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately some older providers (which includes `hashicorp/aws`) produce confusing signals when asked to refresh, particularly in situations where the underlying API performs some normalization of what was previously submitted. For example, in AWS sometimes the API excepts a totally absent "tags" argument when creating but then always returns an empty map when reading.

Terraform's plan UI has some special cases to try to avoid showing those meaningless changes, since they are often confusing. However, as you've seen here sometimes there are *only* those meaningless changes, in which case the UI ends up being confusing in a different way, by hiding the information about what changed.

If you're interested to see more detail here then one option is to view the underlying data that the rendered plan was based on, which you can do like this:

```
terraform plan -refresh-only -out=tfplan
terraform show -json tfplan
```

This returns Terraform's [JSON plan representation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/json-format#plan-representation), which is the underlying representation that the UI then interprets. If you find the object describing the changes to `aws_route53_record.my_record` in there you will hopefully be able to see a benign difference between the "old" and "new" data structures.

---

A situation like this is a bug in the provider, since providers are supposed to detect when two values are semantically equivalent and not report a difference in that case.

However, in practice small quirks like this can remain unresolved because `-refresh-only` plans are used relatively rarely (in comparison to normal plans) and provider teams have to carefully prioritize what they spend time working on.

Comment: "provider teams have to carefully prioritize what they spend time working on" which I definitely agreed with in my comment, but if this can be `PlanModifier` instead of `DiffSuppressFunc` then it seems like low hanging fruit for a team member aside from any strenuous development workflow requirements (and these seemed relaxed the last time I PR'ed to this provider plugin).

Comment: Thanks @martin-atkins ! Looking at the underlying data I see that the `health_check_id` and `set_identifier`attributes have changed from `null` to `""`. Mystery solved! :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing what you learned. It seems like at least for `health_check_id` this is already reported as [issue #21774](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/21774), so you might wish to upvote that issue to reflect that you were affected by the bug.